# Navbar buttons group is not alighed correctly

Tags: html, button, navbar

I am trying to build a nav-bar that would appear on the left-hand side while the rest of the content would be on the right-hand side.  The problem is the nav-bar buttons group is not in the same section with the navbar-header.  I want the nav-bar buttons to align together vertically with the navbar-header on the left-hand side, but right now they just overlap each other.  Not only that, it looks like the buttons group is sitting/overlapping between the navbar-header and the rest of the HTML content.

Much appreciate all the help that can point me to fix this!  Thank you!

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 col-lg-2">
          <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-side">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="./">Lessons</a>
              </div>
              <div class="btn-group-vertical navbar-btn">
                    <div class="btn-group navbar-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                          Lesson #1<span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                          <li>Lecture</li>
                          <li>Quiz</li>
                          <li>Exam</li>
                        </ul>
                        <button type="button" class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
                          Lesson #2<span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                          <li>Lecture</li>
                          <li>Quiz</li>
                          <li>Exam</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </nav>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-9 col-lg-10">
          <div id="lesson">
            <h2>Choose a lesson on the left panel to start your study module.</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: where is your css? do you have a site up or can you make a codepen or jsfiddle?   http://codepen.io/pen/  or  https://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, You seem to be missing a outline CSS.
I assume the code is also incomplete, as I do not see at the very least a "body" tag. Note, if you do have a outline CSS, and you didn't include it, that may also be your issue.

Towards alignment, you can use "margin(-*):[distance][unit];", or "align="[Center, right, justified, etc]"